# Overwrite buffer with system clipboard by ex command

Tags: buffers, ex-mode, register, os-clipboard

I'm trying to find the right ex command to overwrite the current vim buffer with the system clipboard.

The relevant system clipboard register is `"+` in this case.

My first guess was to use `:%+p`; i.e. select the whole buffer `%` and then *paste* `p` the `"+` register to the current buffer. But this doesn't work.

The other way around, [yanking](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/usr_04.html#04.6) the current buffer into the system clipboard is accomplished by `:%y+`; `%` select the whole buffer; `y` copy; `+` to the system clipboard register.

Comment: Based on the answer of @statox , youve got the put syntax wrong. Register comes after.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble Nope, the put syntax isn't *right* if it's put afterwards either. Both syntaxes are wrong. That is, if you mean `:%p+`, by *the registers come after*; it results in an error: `E488: Trailing characters`.

Comment: Darn. I’ll do some reading later this evening. But statox has the right idea (two commands, delete then put)

Comment: @D.BenKnoble Alright! Well, `:%d | put +` doesn't work either, obviously since it's the same command. But, I'll be digging into this too; two commands seem like the right amount. :)

Comment: @MusséRedi `p+` doesn't work because `p` is the print command, `:pu` is the shortest form of put (`:%pu+` is valid but doesn't quite do what you want).

Answer (score 1):

You could add the following in your vimrc:

```
command! ReplaceWithClipboard %d | put +
```

This way when you call the command `:ReplaceWithClipboard` vim will

- `%d` delete all the lines in the buffer
- `put +` put your clipboard register

You can have a look at

- [`:h put`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/change.txt.html#put)
- [`:h user-commands`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/map.txt.html#user-commands)

Comment: This does not work. Even when I tried populating the system clipboard from within vim itself. The message in the header below just reads *--No lines in buffer--*.

Comment: @MusséRedi That's weird it works fine on my setup, maybe try to start Vim without configuration `vim -u NONE`

Comment: Well, it seems that you're right; it works when starting vim without configuration. What kind of configuration settings could be interfering with these two simple commands?

Comment: @MusséRedi Take a look at our famous question [How do I debug my vimrc](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/2003/1841) to find out ;)

Comment: might want to use `sil %d _`  to hide the "no lines in buffer" message and to prevent that the deleted stuff ends up in the clipboard (`:h clipboard-unnamed`). Might as well need `0put +|$d _` to remove the trailing new-line that will be added (without the `0put` it will appear in line 1)

Answer (score 0):

By visual selection, one can (1) select the whole buffer by moving the start of the buffer, with the [motion](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/motion.html) `gg`; (2) pressing `v`, to transfer to visual mode; (3) executing the motion `GG`, to select the whole buffer; (4) accessing the system clipboard register `+`, by pressing `"+`; and finally, (5) pasting the register into the current buffer, by pressing `p`. :)

I still don't know how to do this in the form of a self-contained ex-command though, in which I'm interested.

Comment: is `:0norm!VG"+p` cheating?

Comment: @Mass Could you elaborate?

Comment: `:0` go to 1st line; `norm!` to execute as in normal mode. `V` to visual-line mode. `G` to go to EOF. Now we have in visual mode whole buffer selected. `"+p` to replace selected (whole buffer) to register `+`.